# Regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a list of elements

```
Workset(Name: Ss_75_50_28_29 - Fire Alarm Systems)
Workset(Name: Ss_80 - Lifts and Escalators Systems)
Workset(Name: Ss_25_50 - Facade Access Systems)
Workset(Name: Ss_75_80_45_45 - Lightning Protection Systems)
```

I am hoping to filter just the

`Ss_75_50_28_29 - Fire Alarm Systems`

The regex pattern this isolates what I need but also introduces CR

`Ss\d{2}_\d{2}|_\d{2}|_\d{2}|\s+-\s\w+|\s+\w+`

and also picks up the space before the `Ss`.

Can anyone help me to get to the correct result?

Thanks

Comment: Please write a better title. Also, since all symbols in a regex are important, you **must** make sure your question actually reads like you've meant it to read... Use the code formatting button on things that should be printed in verbatim. You clearly haven't done your due diligence on writing this question!

Comment: Instead of using alternations, you could try `Ss_\d{2}(?:_\d{2})*\s+-\s+\w+(?:\s\w+)*` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxDw7J/2) or do you only want to match `Ss_75_50_28_29 - Fire Alarm Systems` from that list?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I am using python.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, I was not aware of the extra formatting tools.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using alternations `|`, you could use 1 match instead:

```
Ss_\d{2}(?:_\d{2})*\s+-\s+\w+(?:\s\w+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o0ryCK/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DF10Jj)

That will match:

- `Ss_\d{2}` Match Ss_ followed by 2 digits
- `(?:_\d{2})*` Repeat 0+ times an underscore followed by 2 digits in a non capture group
- `\s+-\s+` Match 1+ times a whitespace character, a - and again 1+ times a whitespace character
- `\w+` Match 1+ times a wordcharacter
- `(?:\s\w+)*` Repeat 0+ times a whitespace character followed by 1+ times a word character in a non caputure group

Or if you want to take into account the whole string, you might use a capture group:

```
\AWorkset\(Name: (Ss_\d{2}(?:_\d{2})*\s+-\s+\w+(?:\s\w+)*)\)\Z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lAAeFg/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CqmUiu)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
^Workset\(Name:\s+(.*?)\s+-\s+(.*?)\)$
```

gives you [this](https://regex101.com/r/cfLhfj/1) [regex101.com].